# two auto incrementing columns

Tags: mysql

OK I have hit an issue, now I was going to look at having two auto incrementing columns, but I cant using InnoDB.  So I am after a Solution.

I have a table called queue. Everything to do with my task queue should go into it, But each time something happens with a task I want it to write a new entry, so I can see what has been happening with my tasks. But I also Need a Primary ID for each entry, and a different key for the Tasks

So any suggestions, in how I might go about conquering this small issue.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Queue` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`TaskID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Task` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Client` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`AddedInfo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

Comment: Is this table using the MyISAM Storage Engine ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Queue table is MyISAM, I have just the thing for you.

## OPTION #1

First, you should store task names in its own table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tasks` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Task` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`).
    UNIQUE KEY (`Task`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Then, remove `Task` and `TaskID` from Queue and change the primary key to (TaskID,ID)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Queue` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `TaskID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Client` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `AddedInfo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `Time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`TaskID`,`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Then, you would do something like this each time

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Tasks (Task) VALUES ('Mow the Lawn');
SELECT ID INTO @GivenTaskID FROM Tasks WHERE Task = 'Mow the Lawn';
INSERT INTO Queue (TaskID,Client,AddedInfo,Status)
VALUES (@GivenTaskID,'Rolando Edwards','Valued Customer','Active');
INSERT INTO Queue (TaskID,Client,AddedInfo,Status)
VALUES (@GivenTaskID,'Rolando Edwards','Forgot to Pay','Suspended');
INSERT INTO Queue (TaskID,Client,AddedInfo,Status)
VALUES (@GivenTaskID,'Rolando Edwards','Has Not Paid in 90 Days','Deadbeat');
INSERT IGNORE INTO Tasks (Task) VALUES ('Plant New Flowers');
SELECT ID INTO @GivenTaskID FROM Tasks WHERE Task = 'Plant New Flowers';
INSERT INTO Queue (TaskID,Client,AddedInfo,Status)
VALUES (@GivenTaskID,'Pamela Edwards','First Time Customer','Active');
INSERT INTO Queue (TaskID,Client,AddedInfo,Status)
VALUES (@GivenTaskID,'Pamela Edwards','Made First Payment','Active');
```

## OPTION #2

If you do not want to introduce a new table for tasks then redo the table like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Queue` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Task` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Client` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `AddedInfo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `Time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Task`,`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Then, you would do something like this each time

```
INSERT INTO Queue (Task,Client,AddedInfo,Status)
VALUES ('Mow the Lawn','Rolando Edwards','Valued Customer','Active');
INSERT INTO Queue (TaskID,Client,AddedInfo,Status)
VALUES ('Mow the Lawn','Rolando Edwards','Forgot to Pay','Suspended');
INSERT INTO Queue (TaskID,Client,AddedInfo,Status)
VALUES ('Mow the Lawn','Rolando Edwards','Has Not Paid in 90 Days','Deadbeat');
INSERT INTO Queue (TaskID,Client,AddedInfo,Status)
VALUES ('Plant New Flowers','Pamela Edwards','First Time Customer','Active');
INSERT INTO Queue (TaskID,Client,AddedInfo,Status)
VALUES ('Plant New Flowers','Pamela Edwards','Made First Payment','Active');
```

## EPILOGUE

In both cases, you will have ID of 3 for 'Mow the Lawn' and an ID of 2 for 'Plant New Flowers'

I have done this before. See my posts

- `Apr 21, 2012` : [How can you have two auto-incremental columns in one table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/16849#16849)
- `Feb 26, 2013` : [How to use 2 auto increment columns in MySQL phpmyadmin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin/35479#35479)

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Looks like I have to re look at this.  Having the two tables might be the easiest way to do this.