# Mysql sequential numbering based on MAX of another column

Tags: mysql, myisam, update

I've a table lp_pictures which have these fields:

```
[id | plate_uid]
[1  | aaa]
[1  | aaa]
[1  | aaa]
[1  | bbb]
[1  | bbb]
[1  | bbb]
```

and i need to UPDATE the field id to becomes:

```
[id | plate_uid]
[1  | aaa]
[2  | aaa]
[3  | aaa]
[1  | bbb]
[2  | bbb]
[3  | bbb]
```

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `lp_pictures` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `plate_uid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `ip_submitted` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `date_submitted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `mode_submitted` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `ip_validated` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `date_validated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_validated` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `size` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `combination` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `oldtimer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `owner` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `notify` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `main` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `meaning` text NOT NULL,
  `like` bigint(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `share` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `blocked` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fb_post_id` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The order should be assigned based on date_validated field. (The lower it to the first date).

I need an mysql UPDATE instruction.

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Give us the exact table structure please : `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname\G`

Comment: We need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE lp_picture\G` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## STEP 01 : Create index on `date_submitted`

```
ALTER TABLE lp_pictures ADD INDEX (date_submitted);
```

## STEP 02 : Create separate table to order the `id` values

```
CREATE TABLE lp_picture_ordering
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    plate_uid varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    uid varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (plate_uid,id),
    UNIQUE KEY uid (uid)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

## STEP 03 : Load the table ordering info into the ordering table

```
INSERT INTO lp_picture_ordering (plate_uid,uid)
SELECT plate_uid,uid FROM lp_pictures ORDER BY date_submitted;
```

## STEP 04 : Perform UPDATE JOIN to assign `id` values

```
UPDATE lp_pictures A
INNER JOIN lp_picture_ordering B
USING (uid) SET A.id = B.id;
```

## STEP 05 : Drop the ordering table

```
DROP TABLE lp_picture_ordering;
```

## CAVEATS

#### CAVEAT #1

You needed to add the date_submitted index so the retrieval ordered by date would be fast

#### CAVEAT #2

You will only need to do STEP 01 once

#### CAVEAT #3

STEP 02 creates the increment values for every plate_uid. This technique is only possible with the MyISAM Storage Engine. In my earlier posts, I have suggested using an auto_increment column in a multiple column `PRIMARY KEY`:

- `Apr 21, 2012` : [How can you have two auto-incremental columns in one table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/16849#16849)
- `Jun 10, 2012` : [MySQL get next unique value without auto increment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/mysql-get-next-unique-value-without-auto-increment/19020#19020)
- `Feb 26, 2013` : [How to use 2 auto increment columns in MySQL phpmyadmin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin/35479#35479)
- `Aug 28, 2013` : [How to go about modeling the main object of relationship?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48855/how-to-go-about-modeling-the-main-object-of-relationship/48856#48856)

#### CAVEAT #4

In STEP 03, the id values are generated by the Storage Engine.

#### CAVEAT #5

The ordering table includes uid with a UNIQUE KEY so that STEP 04 can do an INNER JOIN

#### CAVEAT #6

When your done, no need to keep the ordering table. That's why I drop it.

#### CAVEAT #7

Should you ever need to do this again, just do Steps 2-5

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Nice job.. Just a syntax error on STEP 02 block me.

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id,plate_uid),
    UNIQUE KEY uid (uid)
) ENGINE=MyISAM' at line 6

Comment: Forgot the pesky comma. Sorry.

Comment: The result isn't the attended one. As you can see, the numbering should restart at each plate_uid change

Comment: My mistake. I had the `lp_picture_ordering` of the PRIMARY KEY in the wrong order. I'll reverse it in the above code. Then, try it again. When you complete STEP 03, run `SELECT * FROM lp_picture_ordering LIMIT 20;` Look at the output. If the ordering is correct there, the order will be correct afterwards.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you VERY MUCH !!