# Optimize MAX or ORDER BY column DESC with LIMIT 1

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam, query-performance

I have a scenario where I need to Insert a new record and increase a sub-id. 
The Query is very slow. 
Exist any better Solutions for this?

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `link_` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `duid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `domain_id` (`domain_id`),
  KEY `duid` (`duid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Solution 1

```
INSERT INTO link_ (duid, domain_id)
SELECT
    IFNULL(MAX(duid), 0) + 1 AS duid, 5
FROM
link_
WHERE domain_id = 5;
```

Solution 2

```
INSERT INTO link_ (duid, domain_id)
SELECT
    IFNULL(duid, 0) + 1 AS duid, 5
FROM
    link_
WHERE domain_id = 5
ORDER BY duid DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to redesign this table, but I think you will love to do so. Why ???

Did you know that MyISAM supports having an auto_increment id grouped to a key ?

In the [MySQL Documentation for using auto_increment under the subheading `MyISAM Notes`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

MyISAM will do all the heavy lifting of assigning the next `du_id` for each `domain_id`

I discussed this a few times before

- `Aug 28, 2013` : [How to go about modeling the main object of relationship?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48855/how-to-go-about-modeling-the-main-object-of-relationship/48856#48856)
- `Feb 26, 2013` : [How to use 2 auto increment columns in MySQL phpmyadmin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin/35479#35479) (Sample Code)
- `Jun 10, 2012` : [MySQL get next unique value without auto increment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/mysql-get-next-unique-value-without-auto-increment/19020#19020)
- `Apr 21, 2012` : [How can you have two auto-incremental columns in one table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/16849#16849)

#### HOW TO MAKE USE OF THIS

Change the table's design to look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `link_` (
  `duid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`,`du_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You would eliminate `id` (saving 8 bytes per row) and remove a needless index.

Then, your INSERTs would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO link_ (domain_id) VALUES (5);
```

That's it !!! All the auto_increment stuff is handled for you !!!

[Please look over the sample code I mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin/35479#35479).

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Yeah, +5! I was planning to answer like this one!

Comment: There is probably one single feature that MyISAM has these days that InnoDB doesn't. It's this one.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Awesome! This was THE Solution, thank you very much! Now I love MyISAM much more.

Comment: @nenad007 - But try to avoid MyISAM; it is effectively deprecated by Oracle.

Comment: @RickJames I would if I would have another engine that could deliver the same performance as MyISAM on above problem. On the actual server InnoDB took 1.5 seconds per Insert vs 30 ms of MyISAM.

Comment: @nenad007 - To speed up InnoDB `INSERTs`, use `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` and batch 100-1000 rows at a time.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you, but I have master>slave replication therefore I can not do innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 regarding mysql doc, I'm also not able to build batches in the actual usage. Seems my only option is MyISAM or move to another database like PostgreSQL that deliver better performance for this kind of work.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `link_`
ADD INDEX (`domain_id`,`duid`)
```

With this index your first query should work well. You may have to switch your engine to InnoDB, but I'm not sure, as I have no experience with MyISAM.

Comment: Thank you, I had them already but removed separate Index for domain_id and duid, the speed is a little faster but it takes still near 1 second (actual 3m records growing). I tried InnoDB there got Issues with Insert as did not used transactions, but I have the feeld MyISAM should be faster on this.

Comment: The answer here is possibly the best for InnoDB.  Rolando's is better for MyISAM.  MyISAM has no transaction support.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an index which contains both domain_id and duid should indeed speed up the query in your first solution. Moreover though, this will make one of your existing indexes unnecessary. Indexes "short-circuit" so an index on (domain_id, duid) will work just as effectively for domain_id queries as for domain_id+duid queries, but not the reverse, since duid appears second. If you think carefully about the combination of filters likely to be used in queries, you can be more efficient with creating a minimally covering set.