# mysql - can a replica have a different primary key than the source?

Tags: mysql, replication, primary-key

I have a table with `` PRIMARY KEY (`id`) `` and I want to change it to `` PRIMARY KEY (`username`, `id`) ``.  These columns are defined as:

```sql
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

This table is within a primary/secondary MySQL topology with binary row replication.  Can I get away with taking the replica offline, changing the primary key, and reconnect it to the source without changing the source?  For clarity, only the primary key index would be different between the source/replica.  All other columns/order of columns would be the same.

Comment: Easier to just have an additional index on the slave?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ, the idea here is that i would promote the slave, and then upgrade the old master to have the same primary key.  My goal is to reduce I/O required when selecting a group of "messages" for a single "username".  A composite primary key should cluster sequential rows for each user rather than having them randomly spread out based on the primary ID

Comment: What is the value of `binlog_format`?  Do you need `id` for anything?  I approve of the ultimate goal as a performance boost; I have seen it help.  But we need more info to look for gotchas.  You would have to add `INDEX(id)` to keep `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy.  Is there something else that could pair with `username` to be unique?  How many indexes?  Is it InnoDB?  Show us the other secondary keys; they may need changing.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the Storage Engine

## InnoDB

The auto_increment column will behave but the Replica will become very bloated. Why ???

For any given non-unique index in an InnoDB table, each entry in s secondary index will have a copy of the ***`PRIMARY KEY`*** as part of the entry.

If your InnoDB table has `PRIMARY KEY (id)` (which is 8 bytes), then each secondary index entry will have the `id` attached.

Now if you change the ***`PRIMARY KEY`*** to `(username,id)`, then each secondary index entry will have the (`username`,`id`) attached. That can be up to 28 (8 + 20) bytes to each entry.

This will make INSERTs slower on the Replica.

This also allow duplicates of `username`.

You are better off creating a ***`UNIQUE KEY`*** on `username`.

## MyISAM

For those still using MyISAM, PLEASE DO NOT ATTEMPT THIS UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES !!! Why ???

Any MyISAM table that has a compound key that involves an auto_increment column with increment based on the presences of the other columns

#### [EXAMPLE from the MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html)

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');
SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;
```

which prints out

```
+--------+----+---------+
| grp    | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| fish   |  1 | lax     |
| mammal |  1 | dog     |
| mammal |  2 | cat     |
| mammal |  3 | whale   |
| bird   |  1 | penguin |
| bird   |  2 | ostrich |
+--------+----+---------+
```

Do you see how `id` increments on a common value when `grp` already exists  in the table ?

The Source and the Replica will be so horribly out-of-sync. There will be no way to know which row in the Source belongs to a row in the Replica, and vice versa.

This makes changing the PRIMARY KEY of a MyISAM table totally dangerous for a Replica.

I have discussed this subject over 6 years ago

- `Apr 21, 2012` : [How can you have two auto-incremental columns in one table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/16849#16849)
- `Jun 10, 2012` : [MySQL get next unique value without auto increment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/mysql-get-next-unique-value-without-auto-increment/19020#19020)
- `Feb 26, 2013` : [How to use 2 auto increment columns in MySQL phpmyadmin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin/35479#35479)
- `Aug 28, 2013` : [How to go about modeling the main object of relationship?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48855/how-to-go-about-modeling-the-main-object-of-relationship/48856#48856)

## UPDATE 2019-04-20 08:52 EDT

Of course, it is possible but BEWARE !!! : My post was just about the dangers of doing so. In the event of problems, MyISAM would be an absolute nightmare to unravel. InnoDB would be somewhat OK but you are messing with the PRIMARY KEY.

Back on `Aug 14, 2012`, I have recommended changing the storage engine and adding an index on a replica ([Can I have an InnoDB master and MyISAM slaves with Full-Text for searching?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22422/can-i-have-an-innodb-master-and-myisam-slaves-with-full-text-for-searching/22425#22425)). I still recommend do something like this for older versions of MySQL (When FULLTEXT indexes for InnoDB did not exist yet). The **`PRIMARY KEY`** can be a different story.

I can easily see the EXPLAIN plan of a SELECT being radically different on a replica from the EXPLAIN plan of its source given a completely different order of **`PRIMARY KEY`** columns.

You could never use a tool like [pt-table-checksum](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-checksum.html) and [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html) to reconcile differences should the table become out of sync or replication breaking for unrelated reasons. Why ??? Both tools rely on the **`PRIMARY KEY`** columns. Even with plain MySQL, just running `CHECKSUM TABLE table_name;` would always be different between Source and Replica.

Your hoping for better performance runs the risk of MySQL interpreting the table as not being the same (because it simply won't be the same).

If you looking for the username to be unique, ***FORGET IT !!!*** Having `(username,id)` as a **`PRIMARY KEY`** allows for it. If you already have a **`UNIQUE KEY`** on username on the Source, then the Replica already has the key it needs.

## SUGGESTION

Make sure the Source has a **`UNIQUE KEY`** on the username.

Don't do anything to the **`PRIMARY KEY`** on the Replica. If you want to the Source to have it, then do it on the Source so it transfers to the Replica.

## EPILOGUE

Giving you a simple `it's possible` or `it's not possible` answer would be absolutely unfair to you given the bullet-riddled problems it would produce down the road for anyone who tries.

I would never recommend changing the ***`PRIMARY KEY`*** of a Replica regardless of storage engine or DBMS. If you are still willing to accept the responsibility of changing the ***`PRIMARY KEY`*** on a Replica after reading this, [Godspeed, Spiderman !!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AglV2jLZ4qU)

Comment: Thanks for the post but it’s still not clear whether it is possible or not. Also, username is not unique in this table, but it is indexed. So insert performance would be slower, as rows would be inserted all over the primary index rather than always at the end. But I can about read performance, and minimizing iops required for reading sequential rows per username.

Comment: @ChrisLeavoy - Insert performance would not be that much, if any, worse -- You _probably_ have a few hundred "active" users; that would lead to a few hundred "hot spots" in the table.  That is not really worse than appending everything at the 'end' due to auto_inc.

Comment: @ChrisLeavoy - Yes, read performance with be better for `WHERE username='...' AND ...` when it returns multiple rows _and_ the table is too big to be cached in RAM.  How big (GB) is the table?  What is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM?

Comment: @RickJames, we're looking at a fairly sizable table in the 60gb range, and a million of active users.

Comment: @ChrisLeavoy - Change the PK now, before you get to a million users!