# Issues converting MyISAM table to InnoDB (auto column issue)

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, storage-engine, mysql-5.6

I'm having issues trying to convert a table from MyISAM to InnoDB in MySQL 5.6.

The following is the table dump:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `companies`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `companies`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `uid` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cname` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `rfc` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `dbUseExternal` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dbHost` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dbPort` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dbUser` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dbPass` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dbSSL` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dbDriver` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dbName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`cid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

It works as MyISAM. But, if I try to convert it to InnoDB (or if I try editing this dump to insert it on the command line as a sql file), I get the following error:

`Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

I understand that error - or at least I thought I did. I'm not really using more than one `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and it **is** defined as primary key.

Also, the information I've found regarding the error is always because of an obvious missing key or a duplicate AUTO_INCREMENT definition. One more thing I see generally commented is that *the same is true for MyISAM and InnoDB*.

So, why does it work for MyISAM and not for InnoDB?

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Francisco

Comment: Short story: InnoDB does not allow an auto-incrementing column to be part of a composite (unique or) primary key.

Comment: Actually it does (if you add another index, for `(cid)` alone) but the auto-increment won't work as it does in MyISAM.

Comment: Same problem: [MySQL - convert MyISAM into InnoDB getting error 1075](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616573/mysql-convert-myisam-into-innodb-getting-error-1075/14616736#14616736)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, only MyISAM permits auto_increment values in a composite key. I wrote about this over a year ago : [How can you have two auto-incremental columns in one table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/16849#16849)

According to the [**Book**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127)

[image: picture]

Section 5.7 Page 89 Paragraph 1 states the following:

> The MyISAM Storage Engine supports composite indexes that include an AUTO_INCREMENT column. This allows the creation of independent sequences.

which I know you are well aware of. I simply stated this for the benefit of other readers.

As I stated in [**my past post**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/16849#16849)

> This is not possible with InnoDB based on auto_increment columns being tied directly to the gen_clust_index (aka Clustered Index) !!!

Allowing this would require redesigning the [gen_clust_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html) to accommodate such a mechanism.

Comment: I agree that this is not possible in InnoDB but I seriously doubt it is related to the clustered index. It's probably related to isolation levels and their implementation.

Comment: @ypercube I think you are saying it better than I expressed it. I was thinking of mechanisms, not so much the Clustered Index in itself.