# Auto increment value needs to be changed inside trigger

Tags: mysql, innodb, trigger, myisam, auto-increment

I have a slight problem with a table that I have converted which used to be MyISAM, I have now made it a InnoDB table.

Original structure:

```
id varchar(15),
seqno int(11) auto increment 
Joint PK index on the above 2 fields
```

New structure:

```
auto_id INT (11) auto increment,
id varchar(15),
seqno int(11)
```

The original structure had a joint PK on id and seqno with seqno being auto incremented for each unique id value. It would then return the seqno as the last_insert_id in my web application.

With the new innodb structure, because innodb doesnt support joint primary keys, I've had to add in an auto_id which now has the auto increment.

I then implemented a trigger to generate the seqno unique per id value. My question is how do I set the auto increment id so that it returns in place of the auto_id value? This trigger would be called when I insert into my_table, so that it can calculate the next seqno value to insert with.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `innodb_seqno_trigger`;
//

CREATE TRIGGER `innodb_seqno_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

SET @newseqno = 0;

SELECT MAX(seqno) INTO @newseqno
FROM my_table
WHERE id = NEW.id;

SET NEW.seqno = (@newseqno + 1);
/* HERE I NEED HELP PLEASE TO GET THE AUTO INCREMENT VALUE TO ACTUALLY RETURN NEW.seqno */
END;
//
```

Thanks Peter

Comment: What do you need the value of `auto_id` for?

Comment: _innodb doesnt support joint primary keys_ - is it so?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can get the new value of `auto_id` in a `BEFORE` insert trigger. This will do what you want (if I have understood correctly):

```
CREATE TRIGGER innodb_seqno_trigger 
   BEFORE INSERT ON my_table 
   FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

  SELECT MAX(seqno) INTO @newseqno 
  FROM my_table 
  WHERE id = NEW.id;

  SET NEW.seqno = COALESCE(@newseqno + 1, 1); 

END;
```

Test at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f49c/2)**

But have you thought what will happen if you have 2 separate connections/threads/transactions that try to insert the same `id`?

Comment: Indeed one cannot get value of auto_increment in a `BEFORE` trigger. @ypercube's last comment is acutely important.

Answer (score 2):

> because innodb doesnt support joint primary keys

Wait, what?

Unless a "joint primary key" describes something other than a composite key or compound key as primary key, then, of course, `InnoDB` does support this.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `jpk` (
  `id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `seqno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`seqno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one 
auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

All right, fine... it's not that InnoDB won't allow it, it's just that the `auto_increment` columns has to be declared as a key (index)... so, make seqno a key, and InnoDB has no problem:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `jpk` (
  `id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `seqno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`seqno`),
  KEY `seqno` (`seqno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)
```

Or did I miss something?

Comment: I guess they mean that in InnoDB, if you have `seqno` as AI and `(id, seqno)` as the PK, the seqno created values are not unique per id (as in MyISAM) but unique in all the table.

Comment: On the other, you are of course correct. InnoDB allows composite primary keys just fine.

Comment: @ypercube, thanks... I didn't realize `MyISAM` had such bizarre (in my mind) handling of auto_increment values... I stay as far away from it as possible unless I need spatial indexes or pre-5.6 fulltext.  Another +1 for your answer, then. :)

Answer (score 1):

I wish InnoDB could support auto_increment the same way MyISAM does. I wrote about this before

- `Apr 30, 2013` : [Issues converting MyISAM table to InnoDB (auto column issue)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41217/issues-converting-myisam-table-to-innodb-auto-column-issue/41240#41240)
- `Apr 21, 2012` : [How can you have two auto-incremental columns in one table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/16849#16849)

This being the case, you must accept full responsibility for sequencing the two columns. For starters, you must remove the auto_increment option from all columns that involve your sequencing.

```
CREATE TABLE `jpk` (
  `id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `seqno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`seqno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Your trigger has be [**just as ypercube specified**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45569/877). He gets +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your new structure, the `auto_id` field holds the auto_increment value from where mysql would fetch the "next" if we need it.

The value you want as the auto_increment value can be got using:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='table name';
```

You can directly do

```
SET NEW.seqno = SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='table name'
```

in your trigger definition.