# How can you have a combined primary key for one table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, sequence

I have exactly the same question [as posted here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/16861).
But in my case I do not use MySQL but Postgres. Can this be done with Postgres? All things indicate I can not use a combined index in Postgres, so assuming it can not: what solution would be most recommended?

---

Original question:

I have a table that contains information on invoices of a company. However, this company has two branches, and each of them has a unique invoicing sequence; a "Serie A" and "Serie B", so to speak. However, this is one single company and I do not want to create two invoice tables. Rather, I somehow want to have two different auto-increments for one table. (...)

What I am doing right now is not using the primary key as invoice number (which would be ideal), but rather using a secondary column with the invoice id, which is incremented manually (well, using a PHP script, but it's still not automatic), by checking the latest invoice for that particular series.

This is my current setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
  `id` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `invoicenumber` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `branch` enum('A','B') NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `client` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) COMMENT='' ENGINE='InnoDB';
```

To check the latest invoice, I run:

```
SELECT MAX(invoicenumber+1) AS new_invoice_number FROM invoices WHERE branch = 'A'
```

Comment: If you are using Postgres, why do we still see backquotes and `ENGINE='InnoDB'` in the code?

Comment: That particular part is the original question. This question relates to a MySQL database (see also the link).

Comment: [There ain't no such thing as `Postgre`](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines). Fixed the typos. And of course you can have all sorts of [multi-column indices](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) or [primary keys](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS) in Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has sequences, and you can definitely use more than 1 of them for the same table. For example, the following code generates value for `invoiceNumber` column based on `invoiceType` in the trigger :

```
create sequence seq_1;
create sequence seq_2;

create table table1(invoiceType varchar(10) not null,
invoiceNumber int not null,
constraint PK_table1 PRIMARY KEY (invoiceType,invoiceNumber),
constraint CHK_invoiceType CHECK (invoiceType IN ('Type1','Type2')));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table1_seq_generator() RETURNS trigger AS $body_start$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.invoiceType = 'Type1' THEN 
          NEW.invoiceNumber := nextval('seq_1');
        ELSIF NEW.invoiceType ='Type2' THEN
          NEW.invoiceNumber := nextval('seq_2');
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$body_start$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER biTable1 BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.invoiceNumber IS NULL) 
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE table1_seq_generator();

---------------Testing ----------------------------
   INSERT INTO table1(invoiceType) values ('Type1');
   INSERT INTO table1(invoiceType) values ('Type2');
   INSERT INTO table1(invoiceType) values ('Type1');
   INSERT INTO table1(invoiceType) values ('Type2');
   SELECT * FROM table1;
```

You don't necessary have to do it in trigger, application code itself can get `nextval` for different sequence.

Also, I'd not use `invoiceType,invoiceNumber` as primary key constraint, but rather have surrogate pk and unique constraint on  `invoiceType,invoiceNumber` (or `branch,invoiceNumber` according to your naming ).

Comment: Thanks a lot - I've implemented this and it works as a charm!