# Apply nth occurrence number on each distinct value in a column

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, greatest-n-per-group, auto-increment, snowflake

I have a table with a column of values where each value occurs a variable number of times (i.e., one value may occur 1 time, and another value may occur 3 times).  I need to add a column that identifies the occurrence sequence # of its corresponding value.

Input Table

| SOURCE_VAL |
| --- |
| a |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| c |
| c |

Output table

| SEQUENCE_VAL | SOURCE_VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | c |

What would the SQL for this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mysql 5.5
you can use user defined variables for that

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1
>     (`SOURCE_VAL` varchar(1))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tab1
>     (`SOURCE_VAL`)
> VALUES
>     ('a'),
>     ('a'),
>     ('b'),
>     ('c'),
>     ('c'),
>     ('c')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT IF(@s_val = SOURCE_VAL,@rn := @rn +1 , @rn := 1) As SEQUENCE_VAL, @s_val := SOURCE_VAL   as SOURCE_VAL FROM  tab1,(SELECT @rn := 0, @s_val := '') t1 ORDER BY SOURCE_VAL
> ```
>
> ```
> SEQUENCE_VAL | SOURCE_VAL
> -----------: | :---------
>            1 | a         
>            2 | a         
>            1 | b         
>            1 | c         
>            2 | c         
>            3 | c
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=4c50873aa757f951b9da6d30380643cf)*

Snow flake as row_number for that

```
SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER()
  OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE_VAL ORDER BY SOURCE_VAL DESC) SEQUENCE_VAL 
SOURCE_VAL
FROM  tab1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using MySQL 5.5, I have some interesting news for you. Did you know that the MyISAM storage engine supports an auto increment primary key with a second column ? I wrote about this Apr 21, 2012 : [How can you have two auto-incremental columns in one table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/16849#16849) (See the [MySQL Docs on this Auto Increment feature unique to MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)).

NOTE : In all honesty, no one should be using MyISAM any more. Since you are using MySQL 5.5, I would dare to make this suggestion. [I actually have written examples in that 9.5 year old post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/how-can-you-have-two-auto-incremental-columns-in-one-table/16849#16849).

In reality, you should be using MySQL 5.7 or 8.0 and stay away from MyiSAM. In that instance, you would using [@nbk's answer against InnoDB Tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/298709/877).